# socket_create запускается, но не слушает порт

Tags: php, сокет, udp

Проблема в следующем: запускааю соединение, создаётся порт, но подключиться по нему не возможно.

В netstat -ul 2999:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp        0      0 mydomain.ru:2999        *:*
```

Таким образом видно, что порт открыт, но не прослушивается. Плюс ко всему, какие-то запросы от сервисов проверки порта проходят, а какие-то говорят "Порт закрыт".

На сервере так же стоит fail2ban, но он ведь внешние IP блокирует, а не внутренние порты.

Код PHP обычный и до недавнего времени работал:

```
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket,$ipaddress,$port);
```

Подскажите куда копать? Может в iptables какие запреты стоят, как их посмотреть?

Comment: а что, если это все таки fail2ban? может отключить на минутку-другую и посмотреть? или исключить указанный порт с списка защищаемых

Comment: Отключил fail2ban(видимо правил очень много, 5 минут ушло)
Не помогло, всё равно порт висит занятым и при этом не прослушивается.

Comment: Не помогает даже рандомная смена порта(подключение создаётся, но порт не слушается), складывается впечатление что проблема именно внутри PHP.

Comment: А как именно вы проверяете возможность подсоединения к порту? UDP это же не TCP, там не делается подключение через SYN/ACK как в TCP, туда пакеты отправляются, но без гарантии доставки. Через telnet не получится, можно использовать netcat с флагом -u. Читайте ответ с форума сетевиков [тут](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26541/how-to-verify-that-a-udp-port-is-open).